# Deserializer not unwrapping java objects

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind, objectmapper

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = A.class, name = "a"), 
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "b") )
public interface classX<T extends P, I extends Q> {

  /** @return */ String getProp();

  JavaObjectClass getJavaObjectClass();
}
```

```
@Getter 
@EqualsAndHashCode 
@ToString 
@NoArgsConstructor 
public abstract class classY<T extends P, I extends Q> implements class<Event, Identifier> {

private T obj1;

private String obj2;

private I obj3;

private JavaObjectClass obj4;

protected classY( T obj1, String obj2, I obj3, JavaObjectClass obj4) 
{
  this.obj1 = obj1; 
  this.obj2 = obj2;
  this.obj3 = obj3;
  this.obj4 = obj4; 
}

@Override
public final String getProp() 
    { return obj1.getSubProp(); }

@Override 
public JavaObjectClass getJavaObjectClass() 
    { return obj4; }

}
```

```
@ToString 
@Getter 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
public class JavaObjectClass {

private String L; 
private String M; 
public Instant N; 
public Date O;

public JavaObjectClass(AnotherClass input) { 
this.N= input.getN(); 
this.M = input.getM(); 
this.L = input.getL(); 
this.O = Date.from(N); 
  
 }
}
```

```
@Getter 
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true) 
@ToString(callSuper = true) 
@NoArgsConstructor 
public class A extends classZ<EnumClass> {

private K k;

@Builder //... }
```

I have these following code. When deserializing using object mapper, I get the values of `JavaObjectClass=null` but for `K` I am able to get all the values. I can't figure out why this is happening. For string dataTypes i am able to get the value but when its a java object, then its coming as null.  Basically what i can understand is that it is not able to recognize the object itself.

Is there a way to unwrap the **JavaObjectClass?**

Comment: I feel like you posted too much and also too little code: Are all of these classes with all of the fields really necessary to demonstrate the problem, or could the set of classes/fields be further reduced? Additionally you also didn't post the code that demonstrates the actual problem (some serialization/deserialization code with an assert, for example). And last but not least: you seem to have inconsistently renamed your classes: There's references to `A.class` and `B.class` as well as `classZ` and a class apparently just named `class` (which isn't allowed in Java). Please provide a [mre].

Comment: See `java.io.Serializable` interface.